# Create an empty array in json object with AngularFire

Tags: firebase, angularfire

I am a Firebase newby and I need some guidance please:
I have an array of objects: 'discussions'.
Each object contains another array of objects: 'messages'.
So far I have this code:

```
vm.discussions = $firebaseArray(discussionsRef.orderByChild("end_time"));
```

And when a user clicks on starting new discussion:

```
function createNewDiscussion(){
    var newDiscussion = {
      'category':'politics',
      'isActive': true,
      'start_time': Date.now(),
      'messages': [
      ],
    };

    var newMessage = {
      upload_time: Date.now(),
      user: "fhenderson",
      text: 'xxx',
       .......
    };

    vm.discussions.$add(newDiscussion).then(function(ref) {
      var id = ref.key;
      var test1 = $firebaseObject(discussionsRef.child(id));
      var test2 = vm.discussions.$getRecord(id); // record with $id === "foo" or null

//// need help here

}
```

I am having 2 issues:

1. When 'newDiscussion' object is created in Firebase, I cant see 'messages' array being created at all (maybe because it's empty?). Therefore I cant get 'messages' reference.
2. How to add new 'newMessage' to 'messages' array once a new discussion is created?

thanks.